# Combine multiple blender files

Tags: modeling, import

I'd like to know if it's possible to link a .blend with another .blend file.

For example, I have a House .blend file, but it has no doors. I'd like to add multiple of the same door .blend file to the house, and have it so that if I edit the door .blend file, it will update all of the corresponding doors in the house .blend file, and possibly have it editable in the house .blend file too, where editing a door in the house .blend file would update all other door objects and the door .blend file.

I just find it would make life much easier for making models for things like games, where it's tedious to edit everything in 1 single file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#append-and-link). (Surprising you already used the word in your question!)
This will enable you to import the object and the change in the original file will be reflected.

You might also be interested in the [Scenes](https://easyblend.org/html/data_system/scenes.html). This is a link within a single file.

Comment: Silly me, I should have known! Thank you!